# sql opposite of join

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables which are combined via a MAP table

```
Table ANIMAL:
+------+--------------+
| id   |  description |
+------+--------------+
|  2   |  Ape         |
|  3   |  Lion        |
+------+--------------+


Table MAP:
+-----------+---------+
| animal_id | legs_id |
+-----------+---------+
|   2       | 11      |
+-----------+---------+


Table LEGS:
+------+--------------+
|  id  |     legs     |
+------+--------------+
| 10   |      4       |
| 11   |      2       |
+------+--------------+
```

I need the animals that have no map entry in the LEGS table, something like this:

```
 !(select *  
  from ANIMAL as a  
  JOIN MAP as m ON (a.id = m.animal_id)  
  JOIN LEGS as l ON (m.legs_id = l.id) )
```

which should give me 'Lion' as result

Comment: It is not opposite of join. The question topic is ... misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    animal a
        LEFT JOIN Map b
            On a.id = b.animal_id
WHERE   b.animal_id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c833c/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @OblTobl do you really need to join on `LEGs` table? I guess not.

Comment: this was my thinking too... no need to even involve the LEGs table as it has no data that corresponds to anything else in this context...

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from Animal A
left join Map M on A.id=M.animal_id
where M.animal_id is null;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM animal a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT animal_id FROM Map m JOIN Legs l
                   ON m.legs_id = l.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do a simple query to return all animals with no associated Map record... i.e.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Animal
WHERE
   animal_id not in (SELECT animal_id FROM Map)
```